# Modify the position of the background color in amcharts for negative values

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to change the position of the background color in amcharts which normally starts at 0 even for negative values. You can see that here:

https://codepen.io/laurent777/pen/OJjJyVb

html

```
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

css

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

JS

```
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [ {
  "date": "2012-07-27",
  "value": -5
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-28",
  "value": -6
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-29",
  "value": -4
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-30",
  "value": -7
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-31",
  "value": -5
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-01",
  "value": -3
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-02",
  "value": -2
} ];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = -10;
valueAxis.max = 0;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;

// Add vertical scrollbar
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.marginLeft = 0;

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

Is it possible to have the blue background starting at the bottom of the graph (here -10) and finishing at the curve, rather than starting at the curve and finishing at 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After a few researches, I found the solution. I just had to add these 2 lines (in JS):

```
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.baseValue = -10;
```